# Mex error while running vl_compile in vl-feat

Tags: matlab-compiler

I have recently tried vl-feat in matlab. While i am trying to compile vl_compile the following error is showing up

```
Error using mex C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_25970338003646_3984\vl_covdet.obj:vl_covdet.c:(.rdata$.refptr.vlCovdetMethods[.refptr.vlCovdetMethods]+0x0): undefined reference to `vlCovdetMethods' 
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
  Error in vl_compile (line 140)     
mex(cmd{:}) ;
```

It would be very helpful if anyone can guide me how to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is, that **VL_FEAT does not work with matlab on Windows**.

Without compiling (only matlab setup) vl_sift in Matlab told me: "... **vcomp100.dll required by** ...".
I tried to properly recompile and got the same error message as posted in the question.

In the end recompiling didn't not work for me. This is what worked:

I looked into **C:\Windows\System32** and found that vcomp120.dll and vcomp140.dll existed. I simply copied the vcomp120.dll and renamed it to vcomp100.dll.

Then without compiling (only matlab setup), vl_sift worked in matlab.

Comment: I have tried to install Mingw-w64 compiler using matlab toolbox but it failed. Then your suggestion saved my day.